# Union of 3 sets using javascrip

Tags: javascript, html

```
    function myFunction1() {
        var set1 = document.getElementById("myseta").value;
        var set2 = document.getElementById("mysetb").value;
        var set3 = document.getElementById("mysetc").value;
        
        // calculate the union
        var union = set1.concat(set2, set3).filter(function(element, index, array) {
        return array.indexOf(element) === index;
         });
         
         // [1, 2, 3,]
         // document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = set1;
         // document.getElementById("union").innerHTML = set1;
    }
```

i wanted to get the union of 3 sets and display in the result, im quiet confused actually we also have to display the result in venn just sayin

Comment: im using input type and buttons

Comment: Could you provide an example of inputs and expected result?

Comment: @JLMR provide the input type , :/ is it a select with multiple or a simple text input

Comment: set a = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
set b = 2, 1, 3, 6, 5
set c = 1, 2, 4, 6, 5

union of sets are = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

this is my ideal result

Comment: <label>Set A</label>
    <input type="number" id="myseta" value="123">
 
    <label>Set B</label>
    <input type="number"  id="mysetb" value="123">
 
    <label>Set C</label>
    <input type="text"  id="mysetc" value="123" >
 
 <label>Result</label>
 <span id="res"></span>
 

    <hr>
    <button type="button" onclick="unionFunction()">Union</button>
 <button type="button" onclick="intersectionFunction()">Intersection</button>
 <button type="button" onclick="differenceFunction()">Complement</button>
 <button type="button" onclick="complementFunction()">Difference</button>

Comment: function unionFunction() {
        var set1 = document.getElementById("myseta").value;
  var set2 = document.getElementById("mysetb").value;
  var set3 = document.getElementById("mysetc").value;
    
  // calculate the union
         var res = set1.concat(set2, set3).filter(function(element, index, array) {
         return array.indexOf(element) === index;
         });
   
   // [1, 2, 3,]
         document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = set1;
   document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = set2;
   document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = set3;
     
    }

Comment: im not sure with my function

Comment: but i want to display it in my results

Comment: @JLMR can you give me an example what you want to achieve

you want to type in seta 1,2,3
in setb 2,9,8
in setc 6,2,7

then want the function to display just 2 

?

Comment: the function must me be the union of 3 sets which is if i input set a = 123 and b = 123 and c = 123 the output must be union of set a, b, c are 123. when i click the btn "union" the results must be 123.

Comment: okay i got you i will work on it , and send you results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution for 'union' and 'intersection' based on your question and various comments you made. It's up to you to add 'difference' and 'complement':

```js
function analyzeFunction(type) {
  let set1 = document.getElementById("mySetA").value.split(/[, ]+/);
  let set2 = document.getElementById("mySetB").value.split(/[, ]+/);
  let set3 = document.getElementById("mySetC").value.split(/[, ]+/);
  let combined = set1.concat(set2).concat(set3);
  let result = 'FIXME';
  if(type === 'union') {
    result = Object.keys(combined.reduce((acc, val) => {
      acc[val] = true;
      return acc;
    }, {})).join(', ');
  } else if(type === 'intersection') {
    result = combined.reduce((acc, val) => {
      if(!acc[val]) {
        acc[val] = 0;
      }
      acc[val] += 1;
      return acc;
    }, {});
    result = Object.keys(result).filter(val => result[val] >= 3).join(', ');
  } // etc for 'difference' and 'complement'
  console.log(result);
  document.getElementById("result").textContent = result;
}
```

```html
<label>Set A:</label>
<input type="text" id="mySetA" value="1, 2, 3"/><br/>
<label>Set B:</label>
<input type="text" id="mySetB" value="3, 4, 5"/><br/>
<label>Set C:</label>
<input type="text" id="mySetC" value="3, 4, 6"/><br/>
<label>Result:</label>
<span id="result"></span>
<hr/>
<button type="button" onclick="analyzeFunction('union')">Union</button>
<button type="button" onclick="analyzeFunction('intersection')">Intersection</button>
<button type="button" onclick="analyzeFunction('difference')">Complement</button>
<button type="button" onclick="analyzeFunction('complement')">Difference</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

So try this one

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/zackheisnberg/pen/OJEKRYP?editors=1111)

Use a period, as delimiter between values

```
<label>Set A</label>
<input type="text" id="myseta" value="1,2,3">
<label>Set B</label>
<input type="text" id="mysetb" value="2,3,5">
<label>Set C</label>
<input type="text" id="mysetc" value="9,2,7" >
<label>Result</label><span id="res"></span> <hr>
<button type="button" onclick="unionFunction()">Union</button>
<button type="button" onclick="intersectionFunction()">Intersection</button>
<button type="button" onclick="differenceFunction()">Complement</button>
<button type="button" onclick="complementFunction()">Difference</button>
```

The functions

```
function unionFunction(getarray = false) {
  // first we get the values
 var set1 = document.getElementById("myseta").value;
 var set2 = document.getElementById("mysetb").value;
 var set3 = document.getElementById("mysetc").value; 
  // then we can simply make a new Set
  let union = new Set()
  // we get 3 arrays of each set by 
  let arr1 = set1.split(',')
  let arr2 = set2.split(',')
  let arr3 = set3.split(',')
  
  // when we push same values in the set they won't work
  arr1.forEach((elem) => union.add(elem))
  arr2.forEach((elem) => union.add(elem))
  arr3.forEach((elem) => union.add(elem))
  
  // we print it
  if (getarray) {
    return Array.from(union);
  } else {
  document.getElementById("res").innerHTML =     Array.from(union).join(' , ');
}
}

function intersectionFunction(getarray = false) {
  // first we get the values
 var set1 = document.getElementById("myseta").value;
 var set2 = document.getElementById("mysetb").value;
 var set3 = document.getElementById("mysetc").value; 
  // we get 3 arrays of each set by 
  let arr1 = set1.split(',')
  let arr2 = set2.split(',')
  let arr3 = set3.split(',')
  
  /* this function will make a new array 
  intersection , based on filtering the arr1
  by checking if the value exist in array2 */

  let intersection = arr1.filter(value => arr2.includes(value));
  
  /* then we can find intersection between our 
  result and the arr3 */
  intersection = intersection.filter(value => arr3.includes(value));
  
  // we print it
  if (getarray) {
    return intersection
  } else {
  document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = intersection.toString();
  }
}


function differenceFunction() {
  // let do it a different way :D , find the union
  let union = unionFunction(true)
  // then find the intersection
   let intersection = intersectionFunction(true)
  // then remove the union from intersection this will be teh difference
    let difference = union.filter(value => !intersection.includes(value));
   
  // we print it
  document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = difference.toString();
}
```

Comment: would u mind if i ask another question related to that but diff function now

Comment: i wanted now to get the intersection of set here is the sample output 
 // // IF SET A = { 1, 2, 4, 6}, B = { a, b, c, 6} and C =  {#, %, &, * , $, 6}

    // // Results: intersection of sets = { 6 }

Comment: Hello, sorry i was busy, yes i will complete other functions,  try a little bit though 

Comment: Hi!! aww im sorry, i can still wait until u r not that busy :)). for now, i will try a little a bit.

Comment: do u have discord?  in other ways  i can reach u aside stockoverflow :))

Comment: yes it's zackrad#9698 , i added the other 2 functions ,

Comment: already sent request